# The difference between Google Maps StreetView and Panorama

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to make (yet) another google random streetView game.

The goal is to generate random coords, find the nearest street view and display it. I base on [this API example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-service). But there is no difference between shots from google car and panos made by tourists. You can follow my API link and click on Berkeley Art Museum, there will be panorama of the museum inside.

As for my random coords, 9 of 10 nearest panoramas are tourist photos not street view.

But I need only to get shots made by google car. Anyone knows, maybe there is an option or something?

Comment: [Potentially related enhancement request in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4831)

Answer (score 0):

In the sample you provided by google there isn't panos made  by tourist. All the images are form StreetView.

```
 var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
```

Is the object for access to StreetView Service and

```
panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'));
```

is the the windows on which the result of StreetView service is displayed ( equivalent of map for a google map ). 
So there are no images of tourists but only images of StreetView